# Angular2 ES6 @Input alternative

Tags: ecmascript-6, angular, angular2-inputs

I'm trying to build a `<markdown-component>` using ES6 syntax. The `@Input` syntax sugar isn't supported in ES6 and I can't find a viable alternative.

I'm defining the input in the parent with:

```
<ng2-markdown [source]="source"></ng2-markdown>
```

Then accepting the input using:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'ng2-markdown',
  inputs: [ 'source' ]
})
```

If I add a template I can get it will output the value as expected but there's no way to use the input in the constructor.

This module should actually be a directive, and the `source` value will define the path to the Markdown file being loaded.

Comment: The alternative is correct, but at construction time it won't work. It has to be in ngOnInit at least.

Comment: @EricMartinez Thank you so much. I've been stuck on that for hours. I'll add an answer showing what worked so -- hopefully -- it'll help others.

Comment: You don't want to use `@Input` because it's not ES6 but at the same time you use `@Component`. How come?

Comment: @zeroflagL Class/method decorators are part of the future ES7 spec and can be enabled in babel/traceur. For now at least, member decorators are syntax sugar specific to Angular2/Typescript.

Comment: They are not part of the spec, there's only a proposal yet. And the decorators are for classes and **properties**. But it wouldn't even matter because you have to compile your code anyway and you'll have to do so for a long time. So you could as well use TypeScript. Using something because you hope that it might become a standard sometime but not using something else although you could is weird.

Comment: @zeroflagL No they're not spec, but AFAIK decorator proposal in ES7 **only** applies to classes/methods. Property/function decorators aren't even a proposal yet. You argue that I should target an explicit non-standard (ie Typescript) as opposed to a future standard (ES6/7) because... logic? It may sound crazy to a Java dev but I actually *prefer* JS to the statically-typed equivalent. Either way, I'm not here to axe-grind over subjective preference. To each their own.

Comment: [Decorators make it possible to annotate and modify classes and properties at design time.](https://github.com/wycats/javascript-decorators#summary). My comment is not about preferences nor is it a recommendation. Feel free to read it again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Thanks to @Eric Martinez's comment, I was able to get it working.**

The inputs aren't available until the `OnInit` phase of the lifecycle.

*The following worked:*

```
...
export class MarkdownComponent {
  constructor () {}

  ngOnInit() {
    console.log(this.source);
  }
...
```

I was trying to access the input in the constructor, before the inputs were initialized.

Comment: unrelated, but i've spent the last 1+ hours trying to figure out how to include an external library (also was hoping to use a Markdown parser) into my Angular 2 + SystemJS app with little success -- how did you end up doing it?

Comment: @jjwon I use JSPM to manage imports. It takes care of installing the package, installing dependencies, and mapping everything to labels in config.js. Sorry about the Markdown parser, I literally created that repo yesterday by extracting the component from another project. I'll add a note to warn others to hold off until I can test/verify that it works. If you want to see a working implementation, checkout the repo for my personal site (evanplaice.com).

Comment: @jjwon I verified that the markdown component works when it's installed via JSPM. I also created a separate project to demo its usage. https://github.com/evanplaice/ng2-markdown-component-demo